# Django Class Constant vs Database Lookup Performance

Tags: python, sql, django, database

Given I have a Django model like so:

```
Class Shape(models.Model):
    SHAPE_MAPPING = {
        'square': {'is_symmetrical': True},
        'rectangle': {'is_symmetrical': False}
    }
    is_symmetrical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # other fields go here
```

What is a more appropriate way to query if a shape is symmetrical?
I ran a test lookup in my shell and here were the results:

```
ShapeType.objects.get(name='square').is_symmetrical = 0.0212440490723 seconds 
ShapeType.SHAPE_MAPPING['square']['is_symmetrical'] = 2.86102294922e-06 seconds
```

Ignore the conceptual setup of it being a shape, etc. and assume these are physical properties that are not subject to change. I'm asking: **if (and when) it's appropriate to create a non-rel constants structure at the model class level for faster lookup.**

Comment: You've sort of answered it yourself. If the constants are not subject to change, then put them in the code. If they are, put them in the database. The performance issue can be mitigated with appropriate caching etc.

Comment: The code you're showing isn't doing the same thing, one is looking up a value from a dictionary based on the key of a dictionary. and the other is querying a database *instance* to find out a models value. You can't compare them since they're completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have the timing to show that using a constant if possible will be faster. The timing you got for the constant will not deteriorate over time but if you do a look up in a database it will get worse and worse as the table grows. An index will not help you here because that's a boolean field and the cannot be effectively indexed.

If you decided to use caching instead, the performance would still be slower than using a constant. While cache performance will not deteriorate with growth the overhead of the network call make sure that it's slower than the constant lookup.